# How to case match on a function with optional parameters

Tags: scala, parameters, pattern-matching, anonymous-function

I want to be able to have a method with an optional parameter. When that optional parameter is present, it will call a specific DB query that returns records filtered with the optional parameter. If that optional parameter isn't present, I want it to call a different DB query that doesn't filter by the optional parameter.

The first query is not written yet, but would have the same return structure and types. The second query is written, and works fine without the optional parameter and the cases.

```
def getRecords(id: String, type: String = ""): Future[List[Set[String]]] = {
    case Some(type) =>
        val query =>
            s"""
                | ...
             """.stripMargin
    case _ => 
        val query =>
            s"""
                | ...
             """.stripMargin

    record = get(dbResult).asList.asScala.map(_.toString).toSet

}
```

The error I recieve is

```
The argument types of an anonymous function must be fully known. (SLS 8.5)
Expected type was: scala.concurrent.Future[List[Set[String]]]
: Future[List[Set[String]]] = {

                              ^
```

Can someone please explain to me what the error means? and also how to design my method to work the way I would like it to?

Note: Some of the details of the method have been omitted. It essentially just returns a record of the return type and whatever data was taken by one of the queries.

Comment: `def getRecords(id: String, \`type\`: Option[String] = None): Future[List[Set[String]]] = \`type\` match { case Some(t) => ...; case _ => ... }`.  Note `t` here will be your string, if it exists.

Comment: A simple option is to have two overloaded versions of the function, one with a single parameter and one with two parameters.

Comment: As @Lasf mentioned, `type` is reversed keyword and you shouldn't use it. If it's really needed, then you can use with `

Comment: @Lasf Could you please provide an answer? I can't read it very well. Also if it works (it seems to be the answer, if not at least very close) I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for commenting. I could overloads, but the structure of the code base is designed in such a way that I would be adding not just one method, but essentially double the methods, so I'm trying to complete it in one. I probably shouldn't have used that in my example. It's not called 'type' in my actual method. I have had to change/ omit details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re your comment, sure, here you go:

```
def getRecords(id: String, `type`: Option[String] = None): Future[List[Set[String]]] = {
  val matchResult = `type` match {
    case Some(t) =>  //t is your string
        val query =
            s"""
                | ...
             """.stripMargin
        //do something with your query val
    case _ => 
        val query =
            s"""
                | ...
             """.stripMargin
        //do something with your query val
  }
  //use your matchResult here, whatever that ends up being
  //not sure how this works but just copied from your question:
  get(dbResult).asList.asScala.map(_.toString).toSet
}
```

Obviously you'll have to use `query` somewhere, but I assume you've just simplified that away. If you're worried about empty strings, you can add a guard to your first case clause: `case Some(t) if t.nonEmpty => ...`. `type` is backticked because it's a keyword. If you use a non-keyword name you won't need the backticks.

Comment: I've done exactly what you have shown in your answer. However, I receive a `Type mismatch, found: Unit, required: Future[List[Set[String]]]`. Any idea why? I put in both the same query just to make sure there are no errors. But whether or not there is a query in the `case Some(t)` case, I get this error that extends until the start of the `case None. Any idea why?

Comment: @Chris you probably need to return `record`, by writing `record` at the end of the method, assuming it's already the correct type.  If `get(dbResult).asList.asScala.map(_.toString).toSet` makes the correct type/return value then you can just leave that as your last line as I've done in my answer.

Comment: Without the cases, the `record = ...` line does return the correct type. I'll have another look. Is it possible to do this pattern match without the match being included in the method definition?

Comment: @Chris I edited my answer.  See `val matchResult`.  Also remember you need to use `val` to declare a value, e.g. `val record`. Move it outside of your match block. Unfortunately I don't really understand your question... if you want to match on a method parameter you will need to match inside that method's definition.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thanks very much for your help. Also I didn't mean method definition, I meant just the method name and parameters (the method header, I think?)

Comment: @Chris "signature".  There are ways (it's Scala) but you should not be naughty and just pass it ;)

Comment: That's the one, haha. My mind blanked there. Haha I've managed to compile with no errors so I'm happy enough with that haha. Thanks! :)